# Прога должна выводить слова разделенные символами, но если ввести несколько символов подряд, то она их считает за слова

Tags: c++, строки

Дана строка, состоящая из слов, разделенных символами, которые перечислены во второй строке. Показать все слова.

Прога должна выводить слова разделенные символами. По одному слову в строке. Однако если ввести несколько символов подряд, то один из них она убирает, а остальные записывает пусто как будто "Найдено слово: "

```
 /* Пример:
    Мама,,мыла.раму

    Выводит: 
    Найдено слово: Мама
    Найдено слово: 
    Найдено слово: мыла
    Найдено слово: раму

    Должно выводить:
    Найдено слово: Мама
    Найдено слово: мыла
    Найдено слово: раму */

#include <iostream> 
#include <string> 
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int a, b, i = 0, c = 0, g = 0, v = 0;
    string st;
    string r;
    string ch = " ";
    setlocale(0, "");
    cout << "Введите строку: ";
    getline(cin, st);
    a = st.length();
    if (a == 0)
    {
        cout << "Вы не ввели строку" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Введите строку разделителей: ";
        getline(cin, r);
        b = r.length();
        if (b == 0)
        {
            cout << "Вы не ввели строку " << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            while (i != a)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
                {
                    if (st[i] == r[j])
                    {
                        for (g = c; g < i; g++)
                        {
                            ch += st[g];
                        }
                        c = g + 1;
                        cout << "Найдено слово: " << ch << endl;
                        ch = ' ';
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
            if (c != a)
            {
                for (v = c; v < a; v++)
                {
                    ch += st[v];
                }
            }
        } 
        cout << "Найдено слово: " << ch << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Вы сами-то не путаетесь между вашими `a`, `b`, `c`, `g`, `r`, `v`?

Comment: хах, да нет, сначала писал полными названиями, типа stroka_posle_chistki, потом сократил. Ща вроде не путаюсь

Answer (score 1):

Рабочий вариант Вашего кода.

```
int main()
{
    int a, b, i = 0, c = 0, g = 0, v = 0;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "russian");
    string st;
    string r;
    string ch = " ";
    setlocale(0, "");
    cout << "Введите строку: ";
    getline(cin, st);
    a = st.length();
    if (a == 0)
    {
        cout << "Вы не ввели строку" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Введите строку разделителей: ";
        getline(cin, r);
        b = r.length();
        if (b == 0)
        {
            cout << "Вы не ввели строку " << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            while (i != a)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < b; j++)
                {
                    if (st[i] == r[j] & i >= c)
                    {
                        for (g = c; g < i; g++)
                        {
                            ch += st[g];
                        }
                        c = g + 1;
                        if (ch.length() > 1 && !ch.empty()) 
                        {
                            cout << "Найдено слово: " << ch << endl;
                        }
                        ch = ' ';
                    }
                }
                i++;
            }
            if (c != a)
            {
                for (v = c; v < a; v++)
                {
                    ch += st[v];
                }
            }
        }
        if (ch.length() > 1 && !ch.empty())
        {
            cout << "Найдено слово: " << ch << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте изменить условие `if (st[i] == r[j])` на `if (st[i] == r[j] & i>c)`

Comment: Теперь если ввести 11..22, то выведет 11 и .22 (Обратите внимание на точку)

Comment: измените ваш код на прежний и добавьте в место вывода слов вот этот кусок кода                                                                    if (i>c){  cout << "Найдено слово: " << ch << endl;
                        ch = ' ';}

Comment: Теперь выводит 1122

Comment: Не переходит на новую строку почему-то